# Solving equation using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Given U(x) = ((x^2-1)^2- x^2) / ( x*(x^2-1)) , I'm trying to solve this equation :

U(x)- 1/U(x) = x using sympy and this is my code :

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols('x')
P,Q=x**2-1,x
t=(P**2-Q**2)/(P*Q)
print(solve(Eq(t-1/t,x),x))
```

I got a very long list (squeezed text with 1394 lines ) which is wrong comparing to the right solution i have got on wolfram alpha ( this is the right list : l3=[-0.507713305942872,0.507713305942872,-0.777861913430206,0.777861913430206,-1.46190220008154,1.46190220008154]

How can i get the same result in python using sympy ?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the numeric solutions

```
[-0.507713305942872,0.507713305942872,-0.777861913430206,0.777861913430206,-1.46190220008154,1.46190220008154]
```

to be correct, `solve` is probably not the right tool to use. These solutions are not actually "correct" they are just very very close. `solve` is trying to find an analytic i.e. 100% perfect solution. If you are fine with a little error you should use `nsolve` (numeric solve) instead of `solve`.

Also it seems you have an error in your equation code. I let sympy `nsolve` them, got a solution that wasn't among the WA ones. So I rewrote the equation and got `nsolve` to give me one of WA's solutions:

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols('x')
U = ((x**2-1)**2- x**2) / (x*(x**2-1))
eqn = U - 1/U - x
nsolve(eqn,x,0.1)
```

This yields `0.507713305942872`. Which is the closest solution to the start value of `0.1`.

As Oscar Benjamin has pointed out in the comments you can get all numeric solutions with

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols('x')
U = ((x**2-1)**2- x**2) / (x*(x**2-1))
eqn = U - 1/U - x
Poly(eqn.as_numer_denom()[0]).nroots()
```

By default nroots calculates 50 decimal places but you can specify how many you want by giving a keyword argument like so `.nroots(n=decimal_places)`

Comment: You can get them all roots numerically with `Poly((t - 1/t - x).as_numer_denom()[0]).nroots()`

Comment: Is it possible to get more decimal places foor each solution ?

Comment: @meh98 yes I added information of how to do that to the answer.